# MdDialog disableClose in beta3

Tags: angular, angular-material

Since MdDialog has removed config from their code, I was wondering if there is a workaround for the `disableClose` boolean in the config.

I am trying to build a dialog that ensures that the user will click an action button.

In beta2 it was a matter of configuration​, I'm not sure how to accomplish this manually.

Comment: Please, take a look at this [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SS0CJURVQxg0myEG7SPq?p=preview). For me, the config is working..

Comment: If it works for you then why does the documentation say "The config property was removed from MdDialogRef" ? Does it mean they migrated their properties out of MdDialogConfig and made them accessible in a similar fashion? I'm just trying to wrap my head around the breaking changes. If you can post an answer answering these questions​, I'll make it correct

Comment: @Moshe where are you reading this? I don't see it anywhere in the beta3 release notes.

Comment: @joh04667 https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md under "Other Changes"

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Well, it's depreciated but not yet removed. You can access it in the dialog by referencing the documented token. `constructor(@Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data ...)`

Comment: I looked into it more. It's part of `CHANGELOG.md` but documented in the actual release. As of now, it still works and there is nothing in the code to signal a depreciation. It's also still documented on the official Material reference api site. I would continue using it, and maybe open an issue on the repo inquiring about this.